# Progress info using HttpClient

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httpclient, windows-phone-8.1

I wanted to implement progress bar using 'Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient' in Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight.

**Edit: First Attempt**:

```
private async Task CheckProgress()
{
    var df = httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(uriString, UriKind.Absolute)).Progress = Progress;

    // here i want to stop the execution till whole content downloaded

    // Reason to wait here
    // this client download will be used by one more async method. so i need to wait here till the file completely downloaded.

    // this whole is done in this method only ( requirement)
} 

private void  Progress(IAsyncOperationWithProgress<HttpResponseMessage, HttpProgress> asyncInfo, HttpProgress progressInfo)
{
   // here i getting the progress value.
   // i have already set a call back method that report the progress on the UI.
}
```

**One more attempt**: But getting the Exception `Invocation of delegate at wrong time.`

```
private async Task CheckProgress()
{
    var df = httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(uriString, UriKind.Absolute))

    df.Progress =  Progress;

    await df;
    // here i want to stop the execution till whole content downloaded
}
```

**Question**:

All, I wanted is to stop the `CheckProgress()` Method to keep waiting till the whole download completed.

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at the ManualResetEvent (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: When and how are you invoking CheckProgress()?

Comment: haha, me too... i confused.
Do you have the complete code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the solution of my problem but it is just a little miss in my second attempt:

```
private async Task CheckProgress()
{
    var df = httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(uriString, UriKind.Absolute))

    df.Progress = (res, progress) =>
    { 
       // no separate event handler.
    }

    await df;   
}
```

It is just working fine.

Comment: what about the bytes stored as it's used in http://zetcode.com/csharp/httpclient/ ? I mean, your code looks a bit different. once calling the httpClient.GetAsync(); method